# c# convert soap response object to xml

Tags: soap

I have this response object, from a wsdl:

myResponse **oResponse** = oClient.getResponse(cmyCf,"",cNart,"4.02");

How can I convert the **oResponse** into a Xml string?
The response have'nt a CDA instance!
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

My self solution:

```
        public static string ObjectToSOAP(object Object)
        {
           try
           {
            using (MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter Serializer =
                    new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter();
                Serializer.Serialize(Stream, Object);
                Stream.Flush();
                return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)Stream.Position);
            }
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
```

For anyone who has the same problem ..